# Excel Macro to set a default filename when saving

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am not a programmer, but I understand a little about it. I currently have a macro in word that saves a new document with a default name and current date. I am trying to do the same in excel 2010 but don't know how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is the macro for word that I use.

```
Sub FileSave()
    If ActiveDocument.Path = "" Then
                With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
            .Name = MakeDocName 
            .Show
        End With
    Else
        ActiveDocument.Save
    End If
End Sub

Function MakeDocName() As String
    Dim theName As String
    Dim uscore As String
    uscore = "_"

    theName = "DocType_DocDescription_"
    theName = theName & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")



    MakeDocName = theName  
End Function

Sub FileSaveAs()
     With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
            .Name = MakeDocName  
            .Show                
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You should really try to write it in Excel VBA (by starting with the Word VBA code you have), then see what specific problems you have and ask questions on those.  It looks to me like it would mostly work except for Dialogs function lines may need to be changed.

Comment: First, `ActiveDocument` in Word is `ActiveWorkbook` in Excel.

Answer (score 3):

Use the inbuilt `.GetSaveAsFilename`

The syntax is

*expression.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFilename, FileFilter, FilterIndex, Title, ButtonText)*

Example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret
    Dim InitFile As String

    InitFile = "MyFile" '<~~ You can set Default name here

    Ret = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitFile, _
                                        fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", _
                                        FilterIndex:=1, _
                                        Title:="Save As")

    If Ret <> False Then
        '
        '~~> Code to save the file
        '
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: +1! I'm very slowly today, you are ahead of me with `.GetSaveAsFilename`:)

Answer (score 2):

Updated in response to comment.  Adding this code to a `ThisWorkbook` module will produce the customized file name when any open document is saved.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents App As Excel.application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = application
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    App.EnableEvents = False
    If Wb.Path = "" Then
        With App.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs)
            Call .Show(MakeDocName, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled)
        End With
    Else
        Wb.Save
    End If
    App.EnableEvents = True
    Cancel = True
End Sub


Function MakeDocName() As String
    Dim theName As String
    Dim uscore As String
    uscore = "_"

    theName = "DocType_DocDescription_"
    theName = theName & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    MakeDocName = theName
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I saved this macro in a file called book.xlt, and put it in xlstart folder, its there when I start excel, but it doesn't appear to do anything. Is this the correct procedure?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: What I am hoping is that I can do the same as I have in Word, Which I posted above. In word when anyone saves a new document or does a Save as. the document name comes pre populated like this.

"DocType_DocDescription_2014-02-03.docx"

That way the user knows that they need to put in the document type and the description. The date gets populated automatically.